# How to backup Windows Live Mail data (ex: to move from Vista to 7)

Tags: windows-7, email, backup, windows-live-mail

I am using Windows Live Mail to access my 6 mail accounts including hotmail and gmail. Currently I am using windows vista but planning a clean install of Windows 7. Is there any way I can backup the downloaded mails on windows vista and retrieve it again on windows 7. I do not want live mail to download all mails again (its more than 3GB).